# Use 1 or multiple databases?

Tags: sql-server

I have a database that contains transactional data on a website. When a user makes an application, a transaction is logged.

I'm now introducing more functionality which makes use of semi static data stored in the database. I've no real experience in this field so I'm looking for advice at this point.

The new data will be added exclusively by website administrators.

I'm unsure whether to add the data directly on the website, or add locally and redeploy, (although this would be a data only deployment).

If I added data on the website, I would still require the same data locally to be able to test key functionality, so I would have to re-enter.

In the case of redeployment, should I consider 2 databases instead of 1, so that I would not need to backup and restore the constantly moving transactional data.

Unfortunately I can't consider replication because I'm limited to using the Web Edition of Sql 2008 on the production server and 2008 Express on my local machine.

All advice appreciated.

Comment: How much data are we talking? What is the advantage of it being in a database rather than, say, an XML file?

Comment: I guess I'm trying to future proof as much as possible. I've no doubt that I'll need to write stats back at some point in the near future. Also quite a few tables logically, so wouldn't be a case of just 1 xml file.